# .htaccess redirect with percents in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Having trouble rewriting some old URLS to new urls on the same domain, ideally trying to just use local URLs.

Are the unencoded symbols using percent's causing anissues?

**Old URL**

http://domain.com/Delta_%26_Charlie_Alfa/Delta_%26_Charlie_Alfa.html

**New URL**

```
http://domain.com/areas-groups/view/delta-charlie-alfa
```

**RewriteRule**

```
RewriteRule ^Delta_%26_Charlie_Alfa/Delta_%26_Charlie_Alfa.html /areas-groups/view/delta-charlie-alfa [R=301,NC,L,B,PT]
```

I've used `NC` for no case and `B` to try and escape the percents?

Comment: `%26` is encoded `&`, not a percent

Comment: True, but still this should work even with unencoded characters? Unfortunately I can't alter the old URLs as it's a clients site and we can't change the old one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^Delta_\x26_Charlie_Alfa/Delta_\x26_Charlie_Alfa\.html$ /areas-groups/view/delta-charlie-alfa [R=302,NC,L,B]
```

i.e. `\x26` to match `%26`

Comment: Gives an error, would the underscores need escaping?

Comment: No, it worked on my Apache. What Apache version do you have and what error are you getting?